# retrieve data from firestore with flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to retrieve data from firestore to flutter app. I have a lot of data. So I don't wanted to all the data at once. I wanted to get first 10 documents at once and when press load more, it should give another 10 documents so on. I tried this way.

```
var myWhishlist;
late QuerySnapshot snap;
late CollectionReference userDoc;
retrieve() async {
  userDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('user/' + Uid + "/myItems");
  snap = await userDoc.where('isPaid', isEqualTo: false).limit(10).get();
  myWhishlist = snap.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList();
}
```

In this way I got first 10 documents. How to get next 10 documents? IS there any method available to get like this? Can Some one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing for now is correct, your code will limit the results to 10. If you want more results, you can use or `startAfterDocument` and pass the `document` of the last document retrieved from your previous fetch.

I would suggest creating a standalone method, which is

`Future<QuerySnapshot> example (DocumentSnapshot? document) async {...etc}`

If you don't pass a string to it, run your ordinary query using limit. If a string is passed, use the `startAfterDocument` flag.

```
snap = await userDoc.where('isPaid', isEqualTo: false).limit(10).startAfterDocument(documentSnapshot).get();
```

Comment: startAt expect a list as input. When I try to pass document Id it show need to add list as input.

Comment: I edited my answer, use `startAfterDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at `paginate_firestore` package
https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore